# Differences between pointers and variables in C?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int inc1(int x)  { return x++;    }
int inc2(int *x) { return (*x)++; }

int
main(void)
{
    int a;
    a = 3;
    printf("%d\n", inc1(a) + a);
    printf("%d\n", inc2(a) + a);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm working through a past paper and one of the questions is to track the changes made to a between lines 6 and 9. I kind of understand pointers (referencing to memory location) but if someone could just talk me through the changes made to a throughout this piece of code that would be great.

Comment: Is that possibly supposed to be `inc2(&a)` on the last line of `main`?

Comment: nope, I've written it exactly as it appears in the paper.

Comment: Also I have taken the liberty of editing out some errors in the code which are unrelated to your question.

Comment: Then the code in the paper doesn't compile.

Comment: Does "it crashes" count as a change?

Comment: Could you post a link to this paper, please?  It appears that there are serious mistakes in the code you're looking at, which are confusing the issue.

Comment: Als and Zack are right.  It may compile, but passing the value of `a` to `inc2()` will seg fault.

Comment: I realise it doesn't compile, I think it was shortened down for the sake of putting it on paper. All that matters is what goes on within the main block and I was wondering if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Does anyone know for sure if this is undefined behaviour? `a` is read in the addition in main, modified by `func2`, the `+` isn't a sequence point and I'm not sure if the function call is. This paper seems less reliable every second.

Comment: And even if the ampersand were present: the order of evaluation is unspecified, which would lead to undetermined outcome in the inc2() invocation.

Comment: @user1378224 The problem here is _we don't know what the program is supposed to do_.  It contains a serious bug _which may have been intentional_.  The author of this paper may have been trying to make a point about the difference between using a number as a number and using it as a pointer.  Or they might have typoed a straightforward illustration of how you modify variables through pointers.  We don't know.

Comment: @delnan I think that part is fine. There is a sequence point after the evaluation of all arguments to any function but before the body of the function, and there's another one immediately after it returns. The return values of inc1 and inc2 are not used to modify a. The second number printed is unspecified, because the second operand to + might be read before or after the function call, but the value of a after the two statements is definitely 4. (Assuming the logical correction to the call to inc2, anyway.)  [Reposted without egregious mistake]

Answer (score 3):

I'll explain this nearly identical code that doesn't contain the error in your post:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inc1(int x)  { return x++;    }
int inc2(int *x) { return (*x)++; }

int main(void) {
    int a;
    a = 3;
    printf("%d\n", inc1(a) + a);
    printf("%d\n", inc2(&a) + a);
    return 0;
}
```

`a` is initialized to 3, then *the value of a* is passed to `inc1()`, which returns it and adds 1 using **post-increment**.  This means the actual value returned is still 3.

Next, *the address of a* is passed to `inc2()`.  That means that what happens to the value in x happens to a.  Again, post-increment is used, so what `inc2()` returns is 3, but after the call, `a` is 4.

However, compilers are free to evaluate expressions, such as `a` or `inc2(&a)`, in any order between **sequence points**. This means that the `a` on the right of `inc2(&a) + a` may be either 3 or 4 (depending on whether `a` is evaluated before or after `int2(&a)`, so the program may output either **6 7** or **6 6**.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with pointers, but this program might legitimately (i.e. neither option indicates a bug in the compiler) print either `6 7` or `6 8`.  (Do you know why?)

Comment: @Zack I could see `6 6` if `a` was evaluated before `inc2` (is this allowed?), but I'm not sure how `6 8` could happen.  Explain?

Comment: It could print 67 or 66. Order of evaluation for the + expression is undefined. (only short-circuit thingies are evaluated in order) @Goldilocks: but 'a' can already have been evaluated.

Comment: I got confused about what `inc2` returns, is all.  Yes, 6 7 or 6 6.

Answer (score 0):

The line calling inc1() will print '6' (3+3) [first 3 is from the inc1(), due to post increment operator the incremented value is not returned]. Also since the inc1() called by value, value of 'a' is not affected outside the function.

Now, if the statement of calling **inc2()** in the paper is as following:

```
printf("%d\n", inc2(a) + a);
```

then your code will compile (hoping that you will store a memory location in 'a') but depending on the value in it (in case 'a = 3') at runtime you will get Segmentation Fault, since you are trying to dereference the memory location 3 which is not supposed to be accessed by your program.

Alternatively, if the statement is as following:

```
printf("%d\n", inc2(&a) + a);
```

then inc2() will increment the value of 'a' through pointer (address) but will return old value of 'a' (3) still due to its using post increment operator, but it will increment 'a' anyway and any subsequent access to 'a' will get the new value. The next 'a' will have value '4' because of evaluation is done from left to right, hence it will print 7 (3+4).

I hope it clarifies the difference between pointer and variable in C.